# WebApi set defualt values to all parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, autorest

I'm in the middle of migrating our server from SOAP to REST. I'm using swashbuckle to generate the api documentation and autorest to create the clients.

I have alot of methods with signatures that allow:

1) Nullable values

2) Strings that may allow null values

For instance a method like this:

```
public void SetGlobalDataForSite(string wsKey, int? siteId, string title,
 string keywords, string homepagetitle, bool isValidValue)
```

Doesn't need to have a value for siteId, keywords or homepagetitle.

As far as i know to allow these values to be null i should convert the method to something like this:

```
public void SetGlobalDataForSite(string wsKey, string title, bool isValidValue,
 int? siteId = null, string keywords = null, string homepagetitle = null)
```

Now this causes alot of problems:

1) Since i'm changing the signature it's very error prone

2) It's alot of work, i have about 300 methods to change

3) I also need to change the client code which can induce even more bugs

Is there a way to mark these properties as nullable without changing the signarue? Maybe i'm missing something. Creating a request class for most methods could work, but then again i'm generation alot of useless code.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put in one time effort to convert -- usually safe options can be either accept parameter in the form of object (it can be JObject or class or even Tuple in latest version of C#)

Comment: Yeah, i've messed around and ended up just rewriting all the method calls, turns out it's the safest option, and probably the fastest :)